# Is there any benefit to having a long scarf?

Tags: altos-adventure

In Alto's Adventure, as you perform and land tricks, (grinds, flips, etc), your character's scarf will grow longer. The more tricks you perform, the longer your scarf will be.

**Is there any gameplay benefit to having a lengthy scarf?**

[image: long flowing scarf]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Once you have purchased the Wingsuit, the Wingsuit will activate once your scarf has gotten sufficiently long enough. The Wingsuit will let you fly through the air instead of skiing on the ground, making traversal much easier while it is active.

Comment: Is there any benefit before buying the Wingsuit? The scarf seemed to provide a speed boost while active

Comment: I'm not aware of any other benefits of the scarf, but I haven't played Alto's Adventure in quite a while either. I do remember that after performing a trick you get a bit of a speed boost - maybe that is what you are noticing?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro IIRC, the scarf just indicates your speed.